# Aggregations in gmongo 0.9.1

Tags: grails, groovy, aggregation-framework, gmongo

I need to implement some simple aggregations in my app powered by Grails 1.3.7. The mongodb-plugin of 1.0.0.RC3 ships with gmongo 0.9.1, where the aggregate functions are not implemented.

How can I solve the problem? Are there any hooks to call java-mongo API directly, or maybe there's some other plugin releases which allow aggregations?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made it!

with a little amount of the blood shed, I found a way to use aggregations in gmongo 0.9.1 / mongodb 1.0.0.RC3 / Grails 1.3.7!

HOWTO:

1. you need to replace the mongo-java-driver with a newer version (I used the most recent for now 2.9.3). In Grails it looks like:

   dependencies {
     compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.9.3'
   }
2. In BootStrap or in my case Plugin-descriptor add the following line:

   DBCollectionPatcher.PATCHED_METHODS << 'aggregate'
3. The aggregation invocation looks like:

   def res = Task.collection.aggregate( [ $group:[ _id:'totalTime', time:[ $sum:'$time' ] ] ], [] as DBObject ).results()

and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Mongo aggregation apis exist since 2.1 [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/), probably you might need to upgrade your libraries. 
Here is the mongodb plugin [documentation](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/4.%20Low-level%20API.html) which is talking about accessing low-level api. For grails 1.3.7 take at this [blog](http://compiledammit.com/2012/09/13/using-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework-in-grails/) for details on how to add more recent mongo libs into your Grails application and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967971/mongodb-aggregation-framework-for-grails-1-3-7) seems to have the same issue.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations only work in GMongo 1.0+.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be impossible to do it with the existing gmongo/mongo-GORM. There are too many version clashes: different mongo java drivers, different groovy versions etc. I saw many ClassNotFoundExceptions and alike.

Luckily I don't need the aggregation functionality right now, so I'll just wait and upgrade to grails 2.x and mongo-GORM 1.3++ later